# Java - How to add XML element to root tag?

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML File that looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<allinfo>
  <filepath>/mnt/sdcard/Audio_Recorder/</filepath>
  <filename>newxml35500.3gp</filename>
  <annotation>
    <file>newxml35500.3gp</file>
    <timestamp>0:05</timestamp>
    <note>uuuouou</note>
  </annotation>
  <filepath>/mnt/sdcard/Audio_Recorder/</filepath>
  <filename>newxml35501.3gp</filename>
  <annotation>
    <file>newxml35501.3gp</file>
    <timestamp>0:04</timestamp>
    <note>tyty</note>
  </annotation>
</allinfo>
```

I am trying to add an addition annotation to the XML after it has been created so the XML has an additional:

```
<annotation>
  <file>blah</file>
  <timestamp>0:00</timestamp>
  <note>this is a note</note>
</annotation>
```

What is the best way to find the root and then write a few lines to the XML in Java? I have seen DocumentBuilderFactory get some use from others but I am not sure how to implement it correctly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would not recommend adding an attribute to the <?xml line tags that start with <? are called directives and have special meaning to the parser.  It would make more sense to put it in your <allinfo/> tag.  i.e. <allinfo standalong='yes'>

Comment: @dancran: What have you tried so far? Tons of examples are out there...

Comment: The orginial XML file is written using XMLSerializer and OutputStream, but I don't see how I can use that to re-open the same XML, find where I want to write, then write in more information once the connection is closed to the file. Hence, why I am looking for an alternative way to open a connection to the XML file and add additional information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
    final DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    final Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream("<foo><bar/></foo>".getBytes("UTF-8")));
    final Element documentElement = document.getDocumentElement();
    documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement("baz"));
```

You will get:

```
<foo><bar/><baz/></foo>
```

Comment: Helpful answer. To make it even more helpful can you provide a link to JavaDoc for DocumentBuilder?

Comment: @paul mckenzie looks good, but I have one question. I don't see how it knows to write to the saved XML file. Wouldn't I have to pass in a path some somewhere so it knows where to parse and input?

Comment: Use a javax.xml.transform.Transformer to turn the document into a String and then write the string to a file.

Comment: @paul mckenzie I guess it matters that I am programming with Android. It does not provide the Transformer package. Any other suggestions instead of Transformer that will work?

Answer (score 0):

Load the file contents into a String and use Regex and String operations to perform the insertion.

```
String xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>"
    + "<allinfo>"
    + "<filepath>/mnt/sdcard/Audio_Recorder/</filepath>"
    + "...";
// String xml = loadFromFile();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(<allinfo>)(.*?)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(xml);

if (m.matches()) {
    StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder(m.group(1));
    bld.append(m.group(2));
    bld.append("<annotation>").append("\n");
    bld.append("<file>blah</file>").append("\n");
    bld.append("<timestamp>0:00</timestamp>").append("\n");
    bld.append("<note>this is a note</note>").append("\n");
    bld.append("</annotation>").append("\n");
    bld.append("m.group(3));

    xml = bld.toString();
}
```